# C++ Function Overloading (Function Polymorphism)

Tags: c++

Okay I'm super confused because I read my class notes and listened to the lecture.

If all of the following functions exist in a C++
program and are prototyped first, which does

`TestIt('A', int('A'))` call?

A. `int TestIt(char ch, char ix);`

B. `int TestIt(char ch, short ix);`

C. `int TestIt(char ch = 'A');`

D. implementation dependent

E. none

Is this a trick question?

```
TestIt('A', 'A');
```

would return char char right?

Is it B because short is a type of int?

e.g. `int('A')`

It might be none as well.

Comment: *"Is it B because short is a type of int?"* `short`, `int` and `char` (as well as some others) all are *integral types*, or *integer types*.

Comment: It's not polymorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None, because it's ambiguous.

For `TestIt('A', int('A'))`, the arguments are of type `char` and `int`. Two arguments mean that C) is not a viable candidate. A) and B) are viable.

However, the second argument has to be converted from `int` to either `short` or `char`. Both are integral conversions. Therefore, both have the same rank when comparing the overloads. Two or more functions with the same rank for a given set of arguments (and no tie-breaker applies) => ambiguous.

It would be different if you called `TestIt('A', 'A')` and the candidates were

1. `void TestIt(char, int)`
2. `void TestIt(char, short)`

You can try to find out as an exercise why it isn't ambiguous in this case ;)